# How to get img by its css property jQuery

Tags: jquery

I want to get an img by its css property, on jQuery. the property is margin-left:-1920px.

How can I do that?

I tried `$('img').css('margin-left', '-1920px');
            console.log('img');`
but of course its changing the property and this I don't want. I want to get the element first and then changing the property.
How can I get the element?

my jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var sliderUL = $('.slider').children('ul'),
    imgs = sliderUL.find('img'),
    imgWidth = imgs[0].width, // 960
    imgsLen = imgs.length,  // 4
    current = 1,
    totalImgsWidth = imgsLen * imgWidth;


$('#slider-nav')
    .show().find('button').on('click', function() {
        direction = $(this).data('dir');

    var loc = imgWidth;
        (direction === 'next') ? ++current : --current;

        if (current === 0) {
            current = imgsLen;
            direction = 'next';
            loc = totalImgsWidth - imgWidth;


        } else if ( current - 1 === imgsLen ) {
            current = 1;
            loc = 0;
        }

        transition(sliderUL, loc, direction);


    });
function transition( container, loc, direction ) {
    var unit;

    if ( direction && loc !== 0 ) {
        unit = ( direction === 'next' ) ? '-=' : '+=';
    }

    container.animate({
        'margin-left': unit ? (unit+loc) : loc
    })

}
```

});

my HTML:

```
<body>
<div id="slider-nav">
    <button data-dir="prev"><</button>
    <button data-dir="next">></button>
</div>
<div class="slider">
    <ul>
        <li><img src="img1.jpg" alt="image"></li>
        <li><img src="img2.jpg" alt="image"></li>
        <li><img src="img3.jpg" alt="image"></li>
        <li><img src="img4.jpg" alt="image"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can filter those images with that style using **[filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)**:

```
var img = $('img').filter(function() {
    return $(this).css('margin-left') == '-1920px';
});
```

Comment: It doesn't work. I don't understand why.
This is the part of my code:
` $('#slider-nav')
  .show().find('button').on('click', function() {
   direction = $(this).data('dir');
  
  var loc = imgWidth;
   (direction === 'next') ? ++current : --current;
   
   if (current === 0) {
    current = imgsLen;
    direction = 'next';
    loc = totalImgsWidth - imgWidth;
   });
 
   } else if ( current - 1 === imgsLen ) {
    current = 1;
    loc = 0;
   }

  });`
I want to get the img that inside the fun on-clink is in marginleft:1920px. How can I do that and where should I write it on the code?

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
 var x = $('img').filter(function () { 
   return this.style.marginLeft == '-1920px' 
});
```

Comment: This will only find images that have a directly set style on the object (not via stylesheet).  If that's what you want, then this will work.  But, if you want to include values set by stylesheet, then you need the answer from Felix.

Comment: OP need to use getComputedStyle in that case. But yes, using `$(this).css('margin-left') == '-1920px';` is better option.Not sure what OP is upto.